# datepicker issue while using JavaScript call() function

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am trying to override my datepicker plugin and implement my own custom datepicker. I'm putting my code in a global js file in order to override as soon as the page loads.

```
(function($) {
    var originalVal = $.fn.datepicker;
    $.fn.datepicker = function(val1, val2, val3) {
        console.log(val1); // option
        console.log(val2); // maxDate
        console.log(val3); // 09/06/2017
        // var dp = originalVal.clone();
        // console.log(dp);
        var _options = {
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true
        }

        if (val1 == "option") {
            _options[val2] = val3
            console.log(_options[val2]);
        }
        else {
            _options = $.extend(_options, val1)
        }

        console.log(_options); //Object { changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, maxDate: Date 2017-09-06T06:52:32.449Z }

        return originalVal.call(this, _options);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

This works perfectly as the page loads and changeYear and changeMonth is available along with restriction of max date as 09/06/2017.

Here is my page code:

```
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text"  id="pickDate2" >
    <input type="text"  id="pickDate3" >
    <script>
    $("#pickDate2").datepicker();
    $("#pickDate3").datepicker('option','maxDate',new Date());
    $("#pickDate2").change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("#pickDate3").datepicker('option','minDate',Date.parse(val));
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, after the page loads, when the below code is executed, min date is not set

```
$("#pickDate2").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#pickDate3").datepicker('option','minDate',09/03/2017);
})
```

When, I check the console for my plugin override code, the parameters seem to be fine.

```
console.log(_options);//Object { changeYear: true, changeMonth: true, minDate: Date 2017-09-03T18:15:00.000Z }
```

As far as I know, the JavaScript call function is not executing the second time. I couldn't find anything concrete since I searched the web for it. I want the plugin to accept parameters the second time as well.

Comment: In the above, you never initialize the datepicker on `#pickDate3`.

Comment: Yes i did, above my change function

Comment: No. `$("#pickDate3").datepicker('option','maxDate',new Date());` is a method call, not an initialization. It's ignored if you do it on an element that has never had a datepicker initialized on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calls the original datepicker function, but always as though it were initializing a datepicker from scratch. You're intercepting an `"option"` call and turning it into an init call. Clearly, it doesn't allow multiple initializations.

Instead, you need to detect whether an initialization or "method" call is being made, and do the method call if it's a method call. Separately, there's no need for you to intercept `"option"` unless it's setting `changeYear` or `changeMonth` to something you don't want.

Something along these lines (further tweaking may be needed):

```
(function($) {
    var originalVal = $.fn.datepicker;
    $.fn.datepicker = function(val1, val2, val3) {
        if (val1 === "option") {
            if (val2 === "changeYear" || val2 === "changeMonth") {
                return this; // Ignore it
            }
        }
        if (typeof val1 === "string") {
            // Method call, pass through
            return originalVal.apply(this, arguments); 
        }
        // Init call, ensure our options are set and pass it on
        var _options = $.extend({}, val1, {
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true
        });
        return originalVal.call(this, _options);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The above works for me. Here's your example *without* the change above, just with normal jQuery and jQuery UI *(I added the missing `$("#pickDate3").datepicker();`)*:

```js
$("#pickDate2").datepicker();
$("#pickDate3").datepicker();
$("#pickDate3").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date());
$("#pickDate2").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#pickDate3").datepicker('option', 'minDate', Date.parse(val));
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="pickDate2">
<input type="text" id="pickDate3">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And here it is *with* the change above; note that your `changeYear` and `changeMonth` options are added as intended, and the `maxDate` change is also respected when we change the first input:

```js
(function($) {
    var originalVal = $.fn.datepicker;
    $.fn.datepicker = function(val1, val2, val3) {
        if (val1 === "option") {
            if (val2 === "changeYear" || val2 === "changeMonth") {
                return this; // Ignore it
            }
        }
        if (typeof val1 === "string") {
            // Method call, pass through
            return originalVal.apply(this, arguments); 
        }
        // Init call, ensure our options are set and pass it on
        var _options = $.extend({}, val1, {
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true
        });
        return originalVal.call(this, _options);
    };
})(jQuery);
$("#pickDate2").datepicker();
$("#pickDate3").datepicker();
$("#pickDate3").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date());
$("#pickDate2").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#pickDate3").datepicker('option', 'minDate', Date.parse(val));
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="pickDate2">
<input type="text" id="pickDate3">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @T.J.Cowder , the apply function on method call didn't help as well, issue is same as before. Wouldn't apply be same as call in this case?

Comment: @SauravDangol: No. The `apply` above passes along the original arguments unchanged. But the main change above was properly handling a method call vs. an initialization. I'm very surprised that didn't work, what lib is this?

Comment: ,my datepicker version is 1.8.24.Also, Im being blunt here, correct me if im wrong, im passing arguments as follows:
    if (typeof val1 === "string") {
            var option = {}
            option[val2] = val3
            return originalVal.apply(this, [option]);
        }

Comment: @SauravDangol: Version **of what datepicker**? jQuery UI? Some other one? Re the code: No, you're not passing them along, you're converting a call with `(string, string, value)` to a call with `(object)`, which is seen as an init call. That's why I changed that above, so that when doing a "method" call, we continue to pass `(string, string, value)`.

Comment: Its jQuery UI datepicker 1.8.24. As suggested, I tried passing in (string, string, value). This time the datepicker is not initialized on $("#pickDate3").datepicker('option','maxDate',new Date());

Comment: @SauravDangol: The above works for me, see the added snippets. I did have to add the `pickDate3` initialization.

Comment: the initialization seemed to be the problem as you suggested. It worked as expected now. Appreciate your time and effort.